# How to use UIImagePickerControllerCropRect

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I just figured out a way to change rect for crop box which appears after capturing an image from `UIImagePickerViewController`. This can be done with help of `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect`. But I have no idea how to use it. Originally the crop box is square. I want it to be rectangular.

Can someone share an example with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this using the built in UIImagePickerController functionality. Unfortunately, you can't control the size of the crop box.

[Here is a project on github](https://github.com/yogev77/UIImagePickerWithEditor) that may help you accomplish what you are looking to do (checkout `YSImageCrop.h`).

Basically, the bottom line is that you have to implement the UIImagePickerController functionality yourself. I believe the [UIImagePickerWithEditor](https://github.com/yogev77/UIImagePickerWithEditor) project is a good place to start.

Comment: The project on the github is for cropping an image after it has been taken using the camera or photo album. The Q is about the cropping while taking the photo or viewing a photo, similar to the Chase banking app to capture a check with a custom crop rectangle.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we can do that.

Create the User defined Function like this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);


    return cropped;

}
```

And call this code:

```
UIImage *img1=[self imageByCropping:img toRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 106.6, 106.6)];
UIImageView *image_view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img1];
```

Comment: This is useful if you want to crop the image that the user chooses down to a certain size. As far as changing the crop box so that the use can actually pick the cropped image, the UIImagePickerController down not allow for this.