# Creating our own crop rect in camera overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to state my basic requirement which is to change the frame for crop rect in `UIImagePickerController` for a camera.

I just realized that it is not possible to change frame for crop rect. That leaves me with only one option i.e to create my own camera overlay wherein I can set frame for crop rect. I searched a lot but found nothing. I asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100220/how-to-use-uiimagepickercontrollercroprect) but didn't get anything. I don't even know is it possible and if yes then how to create it and move the crop box, scale it in accordance to default `UIImagePickerController` crop rect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to Implement your own CropRect. First set the

```
[picker setAllowsEditing:NO];
```

Then in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate Push your own CropRect View

```
CustomImageEditor *custom = [[CustomImageEditor alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomImageEditor" bundle:nil];
[picker pushViewController:custom animated:YES];
[custom release];
```

while Pushing view pass the image to the Custom View like this

```
 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 custom.pickedImage = image;
```

In that customView you crop the image.

For croping the image try like this..

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Comment: Let me try that. And how will it move and scale?

Comment: Add the ImageView in the ScrollView and Implement the zoom then you can able to move and scale... For scaling the image refer the code I have posted...

Comment: Crop while taking the photo not after! The above code is not a solution for the question posted above. the editing crop box appears  after taking the photo not while taking the photo.